# How to dynamically set Angular form data

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

I have an Angular form group below. What I want to do is simple, initialize the form and if there is not data coming into the `Input() data` property, then set the form values as emtpy string `''` ready for input from user. However, if there ***is*** form data coming in via the `data` property, then I want to initialize the form but have it pre-populate from the data from input property. I'm using the `setValue` method, but it doesn't seem very elegant. It looks like I'm repeating a lot of the initialization code. Is there a better way?

```
@Component({...})
export class SignupFormComponent implements OnInit {
  Input(): data;
  user: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.user = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
      email: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
  if(this.data) {
    this.user.setValue({
      name: this.data.name,
      email: this.data.email
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: You can also use get and set method for updated value patch with child component form.

Answer (score 0):

Angular make this action more simply:

```
@Component({...})
export class SignupFormComponent implements OnInit {
  Input(): data;
  user: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.user = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
      email: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
  if(this.data) {
    this.user.setValue(this.data) //no need set values separately
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Checkout Demo** here into this [Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wrj4gh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts)

You can basically need only set data directly to control, for very first time initialization.

```
@Input() data;
form: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit() {
   this.form = this.fb.group ({
     nameCtr: [{value :this.data?.dataName || '', disabled: false}]
})
```

If data property is set then it will set default data from property, else it assign default to empty string.